# A question concerning subject-verb Agreement

Tags: grammar

Please consider this line:

*Physical and occupational therapy remain an important cornerstone of motor symptom management in FTD.*

I am confused whether the plural usage of "remain" is appropriate as it is preceded by two singular nouns connected by "and."

*or*

Shall I use the singular form "remains" as the subject in consideration would only be "therapy"?

Comment: You do have only a single cornerstone so presumably "physical and occupational therapy" is only a single thing.

Comment: How did I miss this! Thank you, it makes much more sense now.

Comment: Whether the complement is singular or not is irrelevant. The question is whether _physical and occupational therapy_ is singular or plural; and the obvious answer is that it could be either, depending on whether you are thinking of it as one thing or two.

Comment: @Colin Fine Wouldn't one expect _physical therapy and occupational therapy_ or _physical and occupational therapies_? I think it's more than a Gricean requirement.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Maybe. _Physical and occupational therapy are_ has 24 hits in the NoW corpus, and the majority do indeed have that phrase as the sole subject. One of them reads "Physical and occupational therapy are both forms of treatment ..."  _Physical and occupational therapy is_ has 17, and _Physical and occupational therapies are_ has 6. Generally, _Physical and occupational therapy_ is more than ten times as common in the corpus as the plural. (1076:83)

Comment: Thank you for all of your insights.